# Ssh -x windows and Mac

Tags: windows, mac, virtualization

I use ssh -x (or -y) (on my Mac) to connect on a linux os and I can launch the program and see the GUI on my Mac.

Now I want to do the same thing on a windows host is this possible?

MAC ----ssh -x ----> windows (the place where the program are running).

For now I'm using team viewer is there another solution where I can see only the program e non the entire desktop? (no Citrix)

Answer (score 0):

To do ssh -X, you need to have an X server running on the Windows machine. If you want to do this to use programs on Windows, you simply can't, as Windows doesn't use X.